# R square test in matlab

Tags: matlab, goodness-of-fit, r-squared, weibull-distribution

I did the code for my $R^{2}$ (R square) test in MATLAB but it is not working accordingly.
I want to test the Weibull distribution against my raw data, hence I want to do an $R^{2}$ (R square) test. Below is my code, but the results I obtain are negative. I tried with Gamma and Rayleigh to test, but the code was not even working with other distributions.

Could you please verify this code:

```
sample= N;

h1=histfit(sample,30,'weibull'); 
xdata1 = get(h1(2), 'XData'); 
ydata1 = get(h1(2), 'YData'); 
f = fittype('weibull'); 
[c2, gof] = fit(xdata1',ydata1',f)
```

Output

> c2 =
>
> ```
>  General model Weibull:
>  c2(x) = a*b*x^(b-1)*exp(-a*x^b)
>  Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
>    a =   6.787e-05  (-0.3653, 0.3654)
>    b =       9.961  (-5429, 5449)
> ```
>
> gof =
>
> ```
>        sse: 4.9879e+07
>    rsquare: -1.6634
>        dfe: 98
> adjrsquare: -1.6906
>       rmse: 713.4243
> ```

Comment: Hi fredd and welcome to the site. Your question seems off-topic here because it's only about some code. It would be good, though, if you provided some more information about your problem: What statistical problem do you want to solve? In what way exactly isn't your code not working?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for review of code whose execution can be determined only from additional information about the context.

Comment: hello @COOLSerdash, thanks..i want to test my data with weibull distribution with an rsquare coefficient test. i did the above code, but my results are negative..please look into it. my data is only in 1 column around 5000 data

Comment: Somewhat funnily this is not a "code" question. It is a computational Stats one; see my answer below.

Comment: @usεr Yes, that's what I thought when I reopened it.  Thank you for supplying a constructive answer!

Comment: My pleasure boss!

Answer (score 3):

It is pretty clear than an estimation procedure fails here. No half-reasonable fit results to negative $R^2$.

Based on your last comment and doing *quite a bit* of guess work in the current case you have `ydata1` to roughly correspond to points from the line one would get from binning 5000 points in 30 bins. That means that you are pretty surely looking to values that go 200+ in terms of magnitude; a standard *fit-a-distro* algorithm will not work like that because the scale is quite unlikely for a distributional data. Scale your data (by 1000 or something) and try again. Alternatively look into providing *reasonable* starting values to your algorithm. See the following example where I use as data the absolute values from a simple $N(0,1)$:

```
rng(1234); %Fix your random seed
sample= abs(randn(5000,1));

h1=histfit(sample,30,'weibull'); 
xdata1 = get(h1(2), 'XData'); 
ydata1 = get(h1(2), 'YData'); 
f = fittype('weibull'); 
[c, gof] = fit(xdata1',ydata1',f);
[c_scaled, gof_scaled] = fit(xdata1',ydata1'/1000,f);

>> gof.rsquare
ans =
   -0.7902
>> gof_scaled.rsquare
ans =
    0.8287
```

For the unscaled data the estimation is horrible; I get a negative $R^2$ similar to yours. For the scaled data though the estimation is quite reasonable (well as reasonable as fitting a Weinbull distribution to an $|N(0,1)|$ can be). Try to appreciate what you are trying to do not only conceptually but also computationally. Estimation algorithms aren't black-boxes and a [trust-region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_region) algorithm can only take you so far. Always (really *ALWAYS*) plot your data so you have a sense to what you are trying to do.

Comment: hi, i have matlab 2013a, for me your code does not work at all...:( i am still obtaining errors in the last line..

Comment: (Warning: Start point not provided, choosing random start point. )

Comment: also, i found the coeff of r square work only with weibull.. i tried rayleigh, gamma and other dist and nothing works..

Comment: Hi Freed, I tested my code on both R2012a & R2014a and it works fine. You do not get an error; that is a warning (not an error) and it says exactly what I told you above about reasonable starting values. MATLAB is a nice guy and tells you that "*Hey, this an optimization problem, I know that the solution of optimization problems of this kind can be very dependent on their starting points. I chose some starting values at random!*"

Comment: As for the comment about `Gamma`, `Rayleigh` and other distros not working I would recommend you check the syntax of `fittype`. I have the suspicion that `fittype` does not explicitly allow for these distributions to be directly used. Read the documentation of it in more detail. If you code errs, feel free to ask people at S.O. for additional help.

Comment: hi.. thanks for all those kind guidance. i found something called cftool, which is supposed to find the coeff of R square but alas, it does not use distributions. yeah you are right fittype does nto allow soo many distributions.. do you have any idea about any function which returns all those distributions for the coeff of rsquare? please bear in mind i am not expert in statistics, i am simply an engineer an old one at that..

Comment: No problem fredd! I would be tempted to say that you can use `dfittool` for some data exploration but I do not know if it is does exactly what you want. As a final comment: $R^2$ is "nice" but it is far from a panacea; likelihood can be equally helpful for what you are looking for. Good luck with the rest of your analysis!